# Qt/PyQt: How do I act on QWebView/QWebPage's "Open in New Window" action?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qwebkit, qwebpage

If I have an open QWebView, I like its default context menu with "Open in New Window" as an option for links. However, I can't seem to find a way to act when the user requests a link be opened in a new window. Overriding the QWebPage.createWindow method doesn't seem to work, because the method is not invoked when the user chooses to open a link in a new window.

Any recommendations? I'm using PyQt.

Example code:

```
class LocalWebPage(QWebPage):
    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, webFrame, networkRequest, navigationType):
        print '*acceptNavigationRequest**',webFrame, networkRequest, navigationType
        return QWebPage.acceptNavigationRequest(self, webFrame, networkRequest, navigationType)

    def createWindow(self, windowType):
        print '--createWindow', windowType
        return QWebPage.createWindow(self, windowType)


class Browser(Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, base, name):

        ...
        self.page = LocalWebPage()
        self.webViewMain = QWebView(self.centralwidget)
        self.webViewMain.setPage(self.page)
        ...
```

I have the debugging prints in there to verify that createWindow is not being called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to call the `createWindow` method of the `QWebView` yourself, for example by reimplementing the `triggerAction` of the `QWebPage`, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit

class MyPage(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyPage, self).__init__(parent)

    def triggerAction(self, action, checked=False):
        if action == QtWebKit.QWebPage.OpenLinkInNewWindow:
            self.createWindow(QtWebKit.QWebPage.WebBrowserWindow)

        return super(MyPage, self).triggerAction(action, checked)


class MyWindow(QtWebKit.QWebView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.myPage = MyPage(self)

        self.setPage(self.myPage)

    def createWindow(self, windowType):
        if windowType == QtWebKit.QWebPage.WebBrowserWindow:
            self.webView = MyWindow()
            self.webView.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose, True)

            return self.webView

        return super(MyWindow, self).createWindow(windowType)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWindow')

    main = MyWindow()
    main.show()
    main.load(QtCore.QUrl("http://www.example.com"))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, X.Jacobs. Any recommendation on how to figure out the URL/link the user right-clicked on?

Answer (score 2):

The link that was right-clicked can be found by using `hitTestContent` in the `contextMenuEvent` method of the `QWebView`:

```
def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
  pos = event.pos()
  element = self.page().mainFrame().hitTestContent(pos)
  link_url = str(element.linkUrl().toString())
```